# What is the meaning of File System in java 7?

Tags: java, java-7

Is it a collection of files(Directory) that are arranged in alphabetical order?

Comment: Are you talking about [`java.nio.file.FileSystem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html) or the abstract idea of a [file system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system)?

Comment: abstract idea of file system.

Answer (score 2):

A file system defines

1. a set of root directories (e.g. `/` on Unixes; `C:\`, `D:\` on Windows)
2. a way of composing paths and lists of paths `/` and `:` vs `\` and `;`
3. a definition of file permissions
4. definitions of meta-data like what constitutes a hidden file
5. a mechanism for creating, enumerating, manipulating, and accessing files
6. a way to register for notifications when files change

The last two are especially important, because Java7's new IO packages allow you to virtualize a file system.  Instead of dealing with the underlying OS's file system, an application can implement its own file system.  This can be especially useful for testing when you want to separate the tests from dependencies on the actual file system.